# Alias definition of multiple commands after ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, alias, .profile

I'm logging in and out of a remote machine many times a day (through ssh) and I'd like to shorten a bit the whole procedure. I've added an alias in my .bashrc and .profile that looks like:

```
alias connect='ssh -XC username@remotemachine && cd /far/away/location/that/takes/time/to/get/to/;'
```

My problem is that when I write connect, I first get to the location in cause (on my local machine) and then the ssh connection takes place. How can this be? I've thought that by using "&&" the second command will be run only after the first one is successful. After the ssh command is successful, the .profile/.bashrc are loaded anew, before the second part of the alias is successfully executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the ssh specifically, you're looking for the following:

```
ssh -t username@remotemachine "cd /path/you/want ; bash"
```

Using "&&" or even ";" normally will execute the commands in the shell that you're currently in. It's like if you're programming and make a function call and then have another line that you want to effect what happens in the function-- it doesn't work because it's essentially in a different scope.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried adding the -t option to ssh like: 
`alias cmd='ssh -tXC username@host "cd /location/; bash"'`
and it seems to be now working!
 It's just that the .bashrc is somehow loaded twice; adding a line at the end of that file:
    echo ".bashrc loaded"
 gives two such messages after connecting through ssh to that remote machine. I guess that should not produce any trouble.

Answer (score -3):

**For sequence of commands :**

Try this (Using ;) :

```
alias cmd='command1;command2;command3;'
```

Use of '&&' instead of ';'  - 
The && makes it only execute subsequent commands if the previous returns successful.

Comment: I have actually tried that (";") first but it didn't work. Then I presumed that maybe I should make the "cd" command run only after a successful confirmation of connection from ssh ("&&").